# Solving $n\times n$ determinant using triangular shape

Tags: determinant

I have just started learning to solve nth order determinants by getting it into the triangular shape ( in this way the determinant is equal to the multiple of main or additional diagonal + the determination of the sign ). I have solved a couple of easy ones, but got stuck on this one ( which seems easy, but however I manipulate the rows or columns I can't get it into the triangular shape ).

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        5 & 3 & 3 & \cdots & 3 & 3 \\
        3 & 6 & 3 & \cdots & 3 & 3 \\
        3 & 3 & 6 & \cdots & 3 & 3 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        3 & 3 & 3 & \cdots & 6 & 3 \\
        3 & 3 & 3 & \cdots & 3 & 6 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

If someone could give the solution and explain the crucial steps to solving this, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: See [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for posting mathematical expressions, and the link at the bottom there to the home-grown [Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can subtract the last line from the others which gives you :$$\begin{vmatrix}
   2 & 0 &\ldots&0&-3 \\
   0 & 3 &\ddots&\vdots& \vdots \\ 
   \vdots &\Large{0}&\ddots&0& \vdots \\
   0&\ldots&0&3&-3\\
  3&\ldots&\ldots&3&6
\end{vmatrix}$$
Then subtract $\frac{3}{2} L_{1}$ from $L_{n}$:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
   2 & 0 &\ldots&0&-3 \\
   0 & 3 &\ddots&\vdots& \vdots \\ 
   \vdots &\Large{0}&\ddots&0& \vdots \\
   0&\ldots&0&3&-3\\
  0&3&\ldots&3&\frac{3}{2}
\end{vmatrix}$$
Finally, subtract $L_{i}$ for every $i \in [2,n-1]$ from $L_{n}$:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
   2 & 0 &\ldots&0&-3 \\
   0 & 3 &\ddots&\vdots& \vdots \\ 
   \vdots &\Large{0}&\ddots&0& \vdots \\
   0&\ldots&0&3&-3\\
  0&\ldots&\ldots&0&\frac{3}{2}+3(n-2)
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
   2 & 0 &\ldots&0&-3 \\
   0 & 3 &\ddots&\vdots& \vdots \\ 
   \vdots &\Large{0}&\ddots&0& \vdots \\
   0&\ldots&0&3&-3\\
  0&\ldots&\ldots&0&3(n-\frac{3}{2})
\end{vmatrix}$$
These operations don't affect the determinant so you can apply the formula for a triangular shaped matrix.

Comment: I’ve never seen “subtract A to B”, but always “subtract A from B”. Do you mind if I ask where you’re from? Is that British English?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. I am from France, it was definitely not British English. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about subtracting fractions.